# How to sum predicates values without using list?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Im trying to sum up values from predicates without using list. Suming values and finally get the total of suming those values.

```
%shop(TicketNumber, Client, Month).
shop(1, ash, 12).
shop(2, nelson, 11).
shop(3, rob, 10).

%cart(TicketNumber, Product, Price).
cart(1, eggs, 15).
cart(1, milk, 20).
cart(1, meat, 30).
cart(2, eggs, 10).
cart(2, soil, 5).
```

totalCostShop should return the total cost, for example, shop(1, ash, 12) total cost would be 65.

Comment: Why don't you want to use lists (well `findall/3` and then sum up that list)?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I know, it would best to use findall/3, but regardless im trying to sum without list and I can't get it, I was thinking of using an accumulator and foreach predicate, sum the value of it to the accumulator but I don't know how to splash it in code..

Comment: You can make another data structure that is not a list but why bother?

Comment: You're going to have to use `findall/3` or `setof/3` or `bagof/3` in order to obtain all the results for a query like `cart(1, Item, Cost)` anyway, and that result is going to come to you in a list, so you're stuck using lists for this problem whether you want to or not.

Comment: Why do you want to do this without using a list? Also show a complete example query of `totalShopCost`. It isn't very clear what you want that to look like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A technically correct answer to your question would be to use the predicates from library(aggregate). A simple query:

```
?- aggregate_all(sum(Price), cart(1, _, Price), Total).
Total = 65.
```

You see, no list anywhere! Well, who knows, maybe there are lists hiding behind [`aggregate_all`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/aggregate.pl?show=src#aggregate_all/3), but we can't see them, amirite?

A way to aggregate without creating a a data structure, in constant memory, is to use global state. This is usually not recommended for two reasons:

1. In general, global state is difficult to maintain;
2. In Prolog, in particular, code for manipulating global state is clumsy to write.

Here is how you can iterate over facts and get a side effect:

```
?- forall(cart(1, _, Price), format("~w~n", [Price])).
15
20
30
true.
```

The first argument to `forall` is the generator (in this case those rows in the `cart/3` table that have `1` in the first argument). The second argument of `forall` is the side effect. Now you only have to add to a global variable instead of printing to standard output:

```
?- nb_setval(total, 0),
   forall(cart(1, _, Price),
   (   nb_getval(total, X0),
       X1 is X0 + Price,
       nb_setval(total, X1)
   )),
   nb_getval(total, Total).
Total = 65.
```

(And please see the comment below.)

You could have used other mechanisms for keeping the global state. The most portable would be to insert (well, `assert`) to a table with a single row, then on each step read and delete the value on that row (with `retract`), add to it, and `assert` the result back. I've seen this dance in relational databases, if you need to keep a truly global state for your own (application-level) book-keeping.

In normal use this is unnecessary. **However**, it is useful to know how it is done, which is why I bothered to write all this. We can't have this "you can't have this" shit.

Comment: If you click the (:-) icon near the docs of aggregate_all/3, you get is [implementation](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/aggregate.pl?show=src#aggregate_all/3) and you see it is using special code similar to the above for these cases.